# Cannot read property 'graph' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to get [this](https://github.com/zazukoians/boomerang-server) github project to work. The instructions for the same are

- install using npm `npm install boomerang-server`
- change folder `cd node_modules/boomerang-server`
- start boomerang-server using npm `npm start` or node `node ldapp.js`

After executing the last step, I get `Cannot read property 'graph' of undefined`. How can I fix it? I'am still learning nodejs.

Comment: This is not how it works. Clone the repo instead.

Comment: These are the instructions from its website. What should I do after cloning?

Comment: They also give instructions on how to do it the other way... Look at "Install from sources" instead of npm.

Comment: I get the same error from "Install from sources"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is saying cannot find property `graph` of undefined, which means, somewhere in the code, there is `something.graph` being referred to but `something` is undefined. The error is saying there is no `graph` because the object that is supposed to have it is undefined.

This project is 3 years old, so if you are not running versions from that time period, you could definitely be experiencing a breaking change. I looked in the `package.json` file, and it looks like all the libraries are locked to older versions, but you could still have a newer version of `node` or your database or something like that *could be* causing the problem in code that should work.

I searched the code and found this file here that contains some instances of

```
config.store.graph
config.uac.graph
```

File: https://github.com/zazukoians/boomerang-server/blob/master/lib/graph-module.js

So, I would assume at this point, there is something wrong with `config.store` or `config.uac`. Your task now is to figure out why.

Find that file I linked above, **in your project folder** -- should be `./lib/graph-module.js`, and start putting some `console.log()` in there and see if anything is wrong. You should zoom to the area where `config.store` and `config.uac` first come into existence, and look at them, and look at what they are doing, and see if you can find out how to make them work again.